# intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bmp) image is off center

Tags: android

I am having a tad of an issue when creating shortcuts on my android desktop.

First, I have a 72x72 icon, I load it from my SD card into a Bitmap object.

With that bitmap object I set it as my icon resource.

The problem I am having is when I set it, the image on the shortcut appears off center and cut off. From the screen metrics I get the size as 72x72, not sure what the deal is.

Code:

```
Bitmap theBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/icon.png");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, theBitmap)
```

I've tried resizing it and have got it to work utilizing a canvas, drawable and another bitmap, however when restarting the phone it reverts to a small size.

Using the very same icon as a drawable resource makes it look perfect, but its not dynamic:

```
Parcelable iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
```

Using a Samsung Epic 4g w/ 2.1

Comment: weird..are you using your code against standard home application? 
can you post your code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I looked at the Launcher source code and I saw that there's a bug that causes the icon not to appear correctly if the initial bitmap size is too small.

Scale the bitmap to 128x128 first:

```
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(theBitmap, 128, 128, true);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, scaledBitmap);
```

It'll fix it.

Comment: If I resize the image to 128x128, will it work on all phones? Is this the standard size of a shortcut image - I was under the impression that 72x72 was the correct size.

Comment: It is, but the launcher runs its own resizing code, but it fails for some sizes. Pre-resizing to 128 guarantees that it works correctly. The final result will be, of course, resized according to the resolution of the device it's running on. I'm using this in my app UltimateFavesPRO, it has more than 150,000 downloads, never got any complain about this issue.

Comment: for me , on cyanogen 9 (ICS) , 128x128 doesn't work well but 72x72 works well . how come?

Answer (score 5):

Though it's a thread long time ago, I found a property solution:

```
int size = (int) getResources().getDimension(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);
installer.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, size, size, false));
```